# How to .Select() and change a single property at the same time?

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, properties

I've started with the following statement.

```
return part
  .Descendants("DataMapping")
  .Select(element=>serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader()) as Mapping);
```

Then, it turned out that a property in *Mapping* isn't set via the serializer so I had to update it manually. Luckily, it's the same value all the way, so the following resolved my issue.

```
return part
  .Descendants("DataMapping")
  .Select(element => serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader()) as Mapping)
  .Select(element => new Mapping(element, "blopp"));
```

However, I can't stop thinking that it's a bad design. I'm creating an object twice, to begin with. Also, I had to add a custom constructor, increasing the complexity of the code base.

I haven't found any methods like *.ForEach(e=>e.X = ":)"* and I wonder if it's at all possible to LINQ through a serializably created objects and set a value of a field at the same time.

I'd like the expression to behave like the below example shows. I can't use a second *Select()* because then it'd produce an array of *String* type and I need to keep the original type, only slightly affecting its properties.

```
return part
  .Descendants("DataMapping")
  .Select(element => serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader()) as Mapping)
  .SomeCommand(element => element.Extra = "blopp"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a *statement lambda* where *expression lambda* doesn't suit your needs:

```
return part
 .Descendants("DataMapping")
 .Select(element => 
                { 
                   var obj =serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader()) as Mapping);
                   obj.Extra = "blopp";
                   return obj;
                });
```

An alternative would be creating a list and using `ForEach` method:

```
return part
  .Descendants("DataMapping")
  .Select(element => serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader()) as Mapping)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(element => element.Extra = "blopp");
```

Comment: Oh, so stupid... I forgot that I'm on *IEnum*... That's why I couldn't intellisense myself to *.ForEach()*! +1 for the multiple suggestions.